# How to Batch delete the "Instance names" in Flash

Tags: flash

I have a FlA file, which is a combination of Background image(bg) and multiple Objects(of which few have animations to it). I am trying to Extract the BG and Objects out of the FLA.

But in the process, there is a conflict of Instance name. Is there any way i can Batch delete the instance names of all the objects in the FLA. I assume i do not need instance names for my specific task.

Please excuse me if my question was very silly or not so technical, i am a amateur trying to learn.